# I have error "TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, ms-access, tkinter, pypyodbc

I want to add data to Access by writing it in form of tkinter but I have a mistake. What's wrong? I tried to change the place of `con.close ()` but it doesn't help, I even have another mistake if I put it before `def`

```
from tkinter import *
import pypyodbc
import ctypes

form=Tk ()
form.title ("Add data")
form.geometry ('400x200')

#Create connection
con = pypyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;Threads=3;SafeTransactions=0;PageTimeout=5;MaxScanRows=8;MaxBufferSize=2048;FIL={MS Access};DriverId=25;DefaultDir=C:/Users/HP/Desktop/PITL;DBQ=C:/Users/HP/Desktop/PITL/PITL.mdb;')
cursor = con.cursor ()

a = Entry (form, width=20, font="Arial 16")
a.pack ()
b = Entry (form, width=20, font="Arial 16")
b.pack ()

def Add (event):
    cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO Crime (`Number_of_article`, `ID_of_criminal`) VALUES (?, ?)", (a, b))

Button=Button(form, text = 'PUSH ME')
Button.pack ()
Button.bind ('<Button-1>', Add)

form.mainloop ()

con.commit ()
cursor.close ()
con.close ()
```

The mistake is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Desktop\PITL\ADD DATA.py", line 19, in Add
    cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO Crime (`Number_of_article`, `ID_of_criminal`) VALUES (?, ?)", (a, b))
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc-1.3.4-py3.6.egg\pypyodbc.py", line 1491, in execute
    self._BindParams(param_types)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pypyodbc-1.3.4-py3.6.egg\pypyodbc.py", line 1296, in _BindParams
    if param_types[col_num][0] == 'u':
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Since `a`/`b` are `Entry` objects... I'm going to take a guess you need their values, eg: `a.get()` and `b.get()` in your `Add`...?

Comment: @JonClements, Yes, I need their values

Comment: and does making that change work?

Comment: @JonClements Sorry, I don't understand you. What I have to change or add?

Comment: What do you see different in my first comment after the "eg" different than your current code...?

Comment: @JonClements I should change `(a, b)` in my `Add` to this `(a.get(), b.get())`? If so, it doesn't work

Comment: BTW, you can use `command` option of button instead of button-1 binding. `Button(..., command=Add)` and remove event parameter from Add. `def Add():`

Comment: @Bagacan can you [edit] your question to show that...?

Comment: @Baga repeating "it doesn't help" isn't helping anyone help you... Do you get a different error when trying that or the same one? And [edit] your question with the information.

Comment: @JonClements, If I just change `(a, b)` in my `Add` to this `(a.get(), b.get())`, it doesn't bring any mistake and jost don't work after press button. (I'm sorry if I miss smt, I just don't good in code)

Comment: The only thing you're telling it to do is insert rows into the database... Have you looked at the `Crime` table in your Access DB and see if the text you entered has been added?

Comment: @JonClements, After every change in code I see my table and don't see any progress

Comment: @Baga okay - so `select count(*) from Crime` isn't going up every time you click the button (and making sure you've entered data in the entry fields)?

Comment: @JonClements If I write `def Add (event): cursor.execute ("SELECT * FROM Crime")`, it doesn't show data from table (it has data). But I can write `def Add (event):
    a = ("SELECT * FROM Crime")
    for row in cursor.execute(a):
        print (row)` and it will bring all data from table (I just find such way in the Internet)

Comment: Instead of modifying your program I mean type the query into Access itself... and `cursor.execute` won't show data unless you iterate over it or call `.fetchone` or `.fetchall`...

Comment: @JonClements fetchall wasn't necessary as I just wrote `def Add (event):
    cursor.execute ('SELECT * FROM Crime')
    for row in cursor:
        print (row)` and it worked

Comment: @JonClements Why you want me to write such code?

Comment: @JonClements Hallelujah! It is working. Thank you, I just did some stupid mistake. (`def Add ():
    cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO Crime (`Number_of_article`, `ID_of_criminal`) VALUES (?, ?)", (a.get(), b.get()))
    con.commit ()
    cursor.close ()
    con.close ()` I had to write this

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that your SQL input is working then the tkinter side of this isn't too tricky.

For a start, it's probably easier to do this inside of a `class` to make variable passing easier.

You also don't need to bind to the `button` you can add a `command` attribute to it instead.

See my code example below:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        #create our entry boxes
        self.entry1 = Entry(self.root)
        self.entry2 = Entry(self.root)
        #create out button, instead of binding we associate a command to it
        self.button = Button(self.root, text="Insert", command=self.command)
        #pack our objects
        self.entry1.pack()
        self.entry2.pack()
        self.button.pack()
    def command(self):
        #this command outputs the results of the two entry boxes
        #so this is where you'd implement your database entry
        print("Insert "+self.entry1.get()+" & "+self.entry2.get())
        #above, *object*.get() is used to return the value of the object rather than the object itself

root = Tk()
App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It was not me. I just tried to write my code like you

Comment: Probably someone thinking my answer is too opinion based

Comment: You didn't actually address the error in the question. Instead, you just rewrote the program and omitted the code that was causing the problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley Because the user was trying to reinvent the wheel. I have provided them an alternative script which achieves the same output, using the same libraries and language.

Comment: You don't explain _why_ your code is better. The root of the problem is that the OP was using the widget rather than the value in the widget. Your code  uses the value correctly, but you don't explain that this was the reason. For a beginner, they have no way of knowing what the real problem was -- was it that they weren't using classes? Was it that they didn't name their function `command`? Was it because they used `a` rather than `a.get()`? There's no way for them to learn that from your answer.

Comment: @BryanOakley I've quite clearly stated that using `classes` is to make variable handling easier. And I've explained as to how the output is produced, my code is commented to show this. I have amended to show why `.get()` is used rather than just calling the variable containing the object.